# On support of a distribution vs support of a function

Tags: distribution-theory

Given the following definitions, taken from Wikipedia:

> **Support of a function**. When $X$ is a topological space and $f : X \to \mathbb C$ is a continuous function, the *support* of $f$ is defined topologically as the closure of the subset of $X$ where $f$ is non-zero.
> ${\displaystyle \operatorname {supp} (f):={\overline {\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\neq 0\}}}={\overline {f^{-1}\left(\left\{0\right\}^{c}\right)}}.}$

> **Support of a distribution**.  Suppose that $u$ is a distribution and that $U$ is an open set in Euclidean space such that, for all test functions $f$  such that ${\rm supp}\ f \subseteq U$, ${\displaystyle u(f)=0}$. Then $u$ is said to vanish on $U$.
> Now, if $u$ vanishes on an arbitrary family $U_{\alpha}$ of open sets, then for any test function $f$  supported in $\bigcup \limits_\alpha U_{\alpha }$, (...) $u(f)=0$ as well.
> Hence we can define the support of $u$ as **the complement of the largest open set on which $u$ vanishes.**

---

**Question**. For a given function $g(x)$ and a distribution $u(f)$, assuming $g, f \in {\cal D}(\mathbb R^n)$, how can we define the support of the product $g(x)\ u(f)$? ${\rm supp}\ g \ \cap {\rm supp} \ u $?

Comment: We're getting to the point where we have to be careful about things: if $g$ is as you say then $g(x)$ is not a function; also $u(f)$ is not a distribution; they are both scalars. What you probably wanted is the support of $gu$; yes, that's the intersection. (No, we don't "define" it to be that intersection! It's already defined; one can _show_ that it's that intersection...)

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. How can this be shown? Is there a theorem underneath?

Comment: Well, since $gu$ is a distribution probably you start with the definition of the support of a distribution...

Comment: Right, I'm sorry. But anyway $u(gf) \neq gu(f)$, is it?

Comment: ?????????? What's the **definition** of $gu$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $U$ is the largest open set in which $u$ vanishes; let $O$ be the complement of the support of $g$, so $O=(g^{-1}(0))^o$.

The main step is

> > **Proposition.** $gu$ vanishes in $U\cup O$.

Proof: Say $\phi\in C^\infty_c(U\cup O)$. Say $\psi_1,\psi_2$ is a *partition of unity*: $0\le\psi_j\le 1$, $supp(\psi_1)\subset U$, $supp(\psi_2)\subset O$, and $\psi_1+\psi_2=1$. Let $\phi_j=g\psi_j$.
Then $\phi_1$ is supported in $U$, so $\phi_1g=0$, hence by definition $gu(\phi)=u(\phi_1g)=0$. Similarly $gu(\phi_2)=0$, since $g\phi_2$ is supported in $O$ and $u$ vanishes in $O$. So $gu(\phi)=0+0=0$.

So now you just have to figure out why that's the *largest* open set in which $gu$ vanishes, and then see what that is qed. having just determined that we didn't learn the *definition* of $gu$ before asking the question I'll be stopping here.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @DavidC.Ullrich's answer:

First, to understand these definitions, rather than trying to parse the formalities, it is better for many people to think about *intentions* and *examples*.

So, seriously, the support of a distribution should be an extension (in a colloquial sense) of the notion of support of a "function" (with some ambiguity about the latter! like "almost everywhere" stuff, for example).

The main idea is that "support" cannot be generally (meaning including both classical (=pointwise-defined) functions and "generalized functions" (=which need not have pointwise values...)) defined by reference to pointwise values. This is a hurdle, indeed. Of course, for classes of functions that *do* have meaningful and *stable* senses of pointwise values (like continuous functions), there should be a very good match of senses. But for $L^2$ functions? Almost-everywhere stuff? Sometimes we see "essential support" when talking about measurable functions...

With this adaptation, the seemingly double-negative way to describe (let's not say "define"...) the support of a distribution is inevitable.

It is also correct for (integrate-against-) test functions (and more general classes).

By the way, the operation of smooth functions $g$ on distributions $u$ is exactly defined by duality: for test functions $f$, $(g\cdot u)(f)=u(g\cdot f)$, where the latter action of $g$ on $f$ is by pointwise multiplication. This multiplication can *also* be defined by taking distributional ("weak") limits of smooth functions multiplying test functions pointwise. :)